# Memory leak using node-serialport library on pi zero w

Tags: serial, pi-zero-w, node.js

Ok, I'm scratching my head here. I am playing with the [node-serialport](https://github.com/node-serialport/node-serialport) library and when I run this script, the memory is eaten up at a rate of 2MB per second:

```
var SerialPort = require('serialport');
var port = new SerialPort('/dev/ttyAMA0', {
  baudRate: 115200
});


// Switches the port into "flowing mode"
port.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('Data:', data.toString() );
});
```

I don't even have anything connected to the serial port and it just starts eating ram. The weird thing is that I don't have this problem on a `raspberry pi zero` (without the wifi). The node versions are the same, the `node-serialport` versions are the same, they are both on the same version of Raspbian. I'm at a loss as to where to go next.

Details:

```
root@raspberrypi:# node -v
v6.11.4 
root@raspberrypi:# grep serialport package.json 
    "serialport": "^6.2.0",
root@raspberrypi:~# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Raspbian
Description:    Raspbian GNU/Linux 9.3 (stretch)
Release:    9.3
Codename:   stretch
root@raspberrypi:~# cat /boot/cmdline.txt
dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=tty1 root=PARTUUID=74121984-02 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait quiet splash
```

I thought it might be [this](https://github.com/node-serialport/node-serialport/pull/1572) issue but after upgrading to `6.2.0` the issue still persists and now I'm out of ideas. :(

Comment: `memory is eaten up at a rate of 2MB per second` ... change the baud rate .... see if the 2MB per second changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the bluetooth uses the same serial port, so they were likely fighting.

From the github [issue](https://github.com/node-serialport/node-serialport/issues/1583#issuecomment-399946145) I opened:

> If Bluetooth is not needed, add dtoverlay=pi3-disable-bt to
>   /boot/config.txt and reboot. Now full UART /dev/ttyAMA0 is usable on
>   GPIO14 and 15.

Comment: Oh good catch! (But that probably doesn't change the mem leak issue with that library.) Note however that `ttyAMA0` is not the best choice. [The RPi organization do provide some guidance on this.](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/uart.md)

Answer (score 2):

Find another library. [`node-serialport` seems to leak memory like a sieve!](https://github.com/node-serialport/node-serialport/issues/1477)

You may wish to have a [look at this library instead.](http://wiringpi.com/)